# How do I create a game that runs on Windows, iOS and Android?

Tags: c++, android, game-design, ios, actionscript-3

I use C++ to create windows games and now I want to step into another other OS like Android or iOS. I'm totally familiar with C++ so I tried to create app for iOS using objective C it was working awesome. However, I also want to publish games for Android but not by using Java.

I don't want to create a single game 5-6 times for other platforms. Is their any way that if I create game for Windows then it will work in Android *and* iOS ? Or should I use Action Script 3.0? If I use action script 3.0, will it require Flash player to run the game in Windows, Android, iOS?

Comment: This is a "which technology to use" question. See the [FAQ] about these types of questions. They're off topic because they just end up generating lists of answers (as you can see is already happening), that are then voted on like a popularity contest. That's not what this site is about.

Comment: I don't really think it's "which technology to use" - it's framed in a more general "how do I make a game that will run on these 3 platforms" manner, with a bit of "which technology" alright, but only in so far as it could contribute to an answer.  Maybe removing that element from it could make it a more appropriate question with no need to close?

Comment: @mh01 It's framed that way *now*. I edited it a bit to make it a little better. Though, I'm sure you can agree that the way the answers are heading, people are answering it as if it was a "which technology to use" question. The true answer of how to create a game for all those platforms is "find an engine that supports them all, and use it". The answer is not to suggest engines that might work.

Comment: Yale a look at Haxe/NME. It compiles down to C++.

Comment: Apparently people can't help but answer this as a "which technology to use question", so I'm closing it.

Answer (score 12):

Find an engine that runs on all three platforms (i.e., is [*cross-/multi-platform*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-platform)) *and* meets your requirements. The latter will vary with time and only you know all the requirements you need, so finding the correct engine is left up to you.

Comment: The only exactly correct answer, and also the reason why questions like this are more suited to discussion forums instead of Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

The world of cross-platform is a pain. The most convenient way is to create your game using OpenglES, and then try to do specific ports to other devices.

With android you have to pretty much hack to get it going but it might be worth it. 
Even if the NDK gives you the ability to use c++, it still is really hard to get it going with a simple cross-platform engine.

For android you have to use NDK, and for iOS you can compile c++ with objective-C.

So finally, it all comes down how you want to do it. Either you do it really easy and rewrite your game to Java, C++ and Objective-c ( might be awfully slow, but it´s easier than the rest). Or if you want to go with C++ on all devices and do special libraries for every devices and so on.